# Flutter SDK Card

Tags: android-studio, dart

I'm having a hard time setting up the Flutter SDK Card to enable to create flutter projects. I've downloaded the zip, extracted the flutter files, and updated my path, but I'm still unable to create a flutter project via Android Studio.

Please help me, I don't mind you guys screen sharing with me. I have tried everything. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBCu5.png)

Answer (score 0):

please can you be more specific to tell us the OS you're using.

However, try to redownload the  [flutter sdk](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) more so, I'll recommend using a first layer directory as your flutter SDK path. Use something like this `c:\src\flutter\bin`

More so before you start creating the project, it is recommended that run `flutter doctor` on the command line to make sure everything is perfect and to be able to know exactly where a problem is from.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are some steps to make that work.

1. Install flutter - don't forget to declare in user accounts path variables
2. Configure a AVD in Android Studio

Consider using Visual Studio as it might be easier to use than Android Studio for some people.

Answer (score 0):

(Windows User )
I used another drive for the Flutter SDK and add the path to the flutter SDK path to Path Environment Variable in Settings and restarted  cmd That's what I do.

1. Then Run `Flutter doctor` and see if it is working.
   If not check the path in env and make sure you entered it correct.

if not do step 1 again .

if yes it worked ,

2. run `flutter doctor -v` to check any other problems

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following error comes from no pre-assigned skd path in the environment file in windows. If the environment and path are defined.It is requested to update and install the FLUTTER PLUGIN in android studios. If using the latest version of the IDE going to terminal and using command given below will show all the necessary changes needed for you to fix.

```
flutter doctor
```

If the command says 'flutter command not found' or anything as such please ensure to set your windows or mac's PATH to flutter bin as per documentation.